# Bizarre Firewall Related Socket Leak on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, sockets, resource-leak

I've encountered a strange socket leak issue in Mac OS X I can't explain. I have an open source daemon (olad) that listens on 9010 (tcp), 9090 (tcp) and 6454 (udp) amongst other ports.  When the daemon exits, netstat shows port 6454 is still open and listening:

```
$ netstat -f inet -n | grep 6454
<nothing>
$ olad/olad 
<exit server>
$ netstat -f inet -n | grep 6454
udp4       0      0  *.6454                 *.*
```

However, lsof does not show the socket:

```
$ lsof -i 4 -P | grep 6454
<nothing>
```

Once the system is in this state, by sending packets to the port I can see the queue count increase:

```
$ netstat -f inet -n | grep 6454
udp4     612      0  *.6454                 *.*
```

This only happens if the Application Firewall is enabled in Preferences -> Security & Privacy *and* it's the first time running the binary. That is, if I disable the firewall the leak doesn't occur. Or, if the firewall is enabled, after the first run where the dialog box pops up and I click accept, the problem no longer occurs.

Once the socket has leaked, disabling the firewall fails to release it.

I have confirmed that I'm calling close() on all sockets before the program exits and there are no calls to fork() or new threads.

I'm been trying to narrow down the bug case but it seems to be a reasonably complex interaction between pipe(), socket(), bind(), listen(), ioctl(), fnctl() and select(). Changing the order of calls and removing the listens on port 9010 and 9090 causes the problem to disappear.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to continue debugging this, or a guide on how the Mac Application firewall works internally?

Comment: If you start the server again, does the app successfully reclaim and open the socket on all the associated ports?  What happens when you type `netstat` with the `-p` option to show the associated program with the connection?

Comment: If I enable SO_REUSEPORT the bind() succeeds but the application does not receive any data. The queue counters continue to increment.

If SO_REUSEPORT isn't enabled, the bind fails.

On mac, the -p option to netstat doesn't display the process.

Answer (score 3):

We ran into that issue as well with a network-enabled application on Mac OS 10.14. The result of some investigation is a Python script that nicely reproduces the issue.

```
import socket

udpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udpsock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 7744))

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 17744))
tcpsock.listen()

print("Listening ...")

while True:
    data, addr = udpsock.recvfrom(16)
    print("Received data: ", data)
```

With the application firewall enabled and a sender sending data to UDP port 7744, the OS prompts the user to accept incoming network traffic at the first start, and once allowed, the script will receive the packets. After stopping the script, however, the socket remains open with no matching userspace task using it, and subsequent attempts to `bind()` it again will result in `Address already in use`, regardless of whether `SO_REUSE_PORT` and/or `SO_REUSE_ADDR` were set. After this point, the machine must be rebooted in order for a listener to gain access to that UDP port again.

```
$ netstat -an -pudp | grep 7744
udp4     0      0  *.7744                 *.*
```

Note that this only happens when a TCP listener is also registered, and if UDP packets are being received while the script is running. This might be caused by other circumstances as well, but the above is the most simplified example we could boil the issue down to.

So this is a kernel bug in Mac OS that has been present for at least 4 years now and that apparently affects all tasks that have both a UDP and a TCP listener. Until this is fixed, users are required to disable the firewall option.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the firewall "remembers" the socket options of a previously bound UDP port even after the process using it was shut down. This results in having the UDP port listed by "netstat -n -f inet" without any process receiving from it. From that point on, any attempt to bind a socket to that port will As expected, everything is fine when the firewall is off.

As you have discovered already, OS-X requires SO_REUSEPORT instead of SO_REUSEADDR to avoid this weird state issue with the firewall. Furthermore, the only way to flush the firewall state is to restart. Interestingly enough you need to let a couple of minutes pass before starting the server after a restart. For some reason that I didn't care to research further, if you start a server before the firewall completes its initialization, you don't get the firewall popup asking you to allow access and your server remains "forever" (i.e. until next restart or until you rebuild the server binary) blocked by the firewall.